# sending a multipart/form-data form returning 500 "{}"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, multipartform-data, dataform

I'm trying to send a multipart/form-data form with a file with this json:

```js
module.exports.postFormDataWithFileImport = {        
    method: 'POST',
    uri: '<Mandatory>',
    headers: {},   
    name: 'files',     
    formData: {
        file: {
            value: '<Mandatory>',
            options: {
                //name: 'files',
                filename: '<Mandatory>',
                contentType: 'text/plain'
            }
        }
    },
};
```

**implementation:**

```html
let jsonObject = "";
    let postOptions = postOptionsTemplate.postFormDataWithFileImport;  
    postOptions.uri = url;
    postOptions.headers.Cookie = loginCookie;
    postOptions.formData.file.value = await fs.createReadStream('C:/ImportCMS/file1.txt');
    postOptions.formData.file.options.filename = file + '.txt';
```

**I tried multiple things but I'm still getting 500 response. 
any ideas what am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: Error 500 means an internal server error, so the server that the `url` points to has some error going on on their side. It can either mean the server itself is experiencing problems and you have to wait for the administrator(s) to fix it. Or the data you are sending it is in a format it is not expecting, and causing it to error out. You will have to do some debugging to figure out which one it is as we cannot tell you as we don't know what service you are using, how you are actually transmitting the data, nor what type of data the server itself is expecting.

Comment: @PatrickEvans the server itself doesn't have any issues, that actually a format problem but I'm not sure what is the correct format so I uploaded the question. do you have any idea what might be the right ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what service you are using, or shown how you are sending the data so both of those would be needed in order to help. Note if this is being sent to your own server and your server is giving the 500 error then one of your scripts is erroring out and you need to look in the server error logs to see what is causing it